# Align all descriptions relative to the longest symbol in a nomenclature

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nomenclature, alignment, nomencl

I'm using the `nomencl`-package for a list of symbols. Line breaks are inserted automatically whenever a description of a symbol is too long. However, if a symbol itself is too long, the indentation of the first and second line of the description is not aligned. The following example shows what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{A}{}
]}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature[A]{$a$}{Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz. 123 456 789 101112 131415 161718 192021}
\nomenclature[A]{$foobar123$}{Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz. 123 456 789 101112 131415 161718 192021}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

This is how the rendered output looks like:

[image: nomencl output]

Is it possible to automatically indent all descriptions relative to the longest symbol in the list (`$foobar123$` in the example)?

Comment: Relative to the whole nomenclature, or on a per letter basis?

Comment: @Bernard There should be be an indentation of the description after the last letter of the longest symbol (`$fooa123$`) and the indentation of the description of every other symbol (e.g. `$a$`) should be aligned with that description.

Comment: Looks like you want a table to display the nomenclature instead of a description list (=> the `nomentbl` style)

Comment: @clemens I don't know if what you write is what I want. How could I do it?

Comment: I wanted to answer your question but it seems there's a bug when using the `nomentbl` option. I made a report of this here: https://github.com/borisveytsman/nomencl/issues/7

Comment: @clemens On overleaf your MWE is compiling and yields the desired output.

Comment: @0xbadf00d my guess is that overleaf uses an older version... They probably only update once or twice a year…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve the problem is to set the distance between the symbol and its description manually in the preamble of the document:

```
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{xcm}
```

(where `x` is replaced with a suitably chosen value).